# Call custom controller action from view when I click on a button Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller, action

I'm struggling with a simple action call in rails and i cannot find what is wrong and why many solutions don't work in my case. I mention that i'm a new guy to rails, coming from Java world.

The problem is like that:
I want to have a button in my view which points to a controller action, an action that changes a column in a table.

routes.rb

> post 'punch/userout' => 'punch#userout', :as => :userout

view: *punch\out.erb*

```
 <%= link_to('Out', userout_path, method: :post)  %>
```

controller: punch_controller.rb

```
  
class PunchController  ApplicationController
    before_filter :authorize_admin, only: :index
    layout 'application'
    layout false, :except  => :new 

  # GET method to get all products from database
  def index
    #@punchins = Punchin.all
    @filterrific = initialize_filterrific(
        Punchin,
        params[:filterrific]
    ) or return

    @punchins = @filterrific.find.page(params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end

    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    # There is an issue with the persisted param_set. Reset it.
    puts "Had to reset filterrific params: #{ e.message }"
    redirect_to(reset_filterrific_url(format: :html)) and return
  end

  # GET method for the new product form
  def new
    @punchin = Punchin.new
     if current_user.admin
       redirect_to root_path
=begin
     elsif current_user.punched_in
       redirect_to punch_out_path
=end
     end
  end

  # POST method for processing form data
  def create
    #@punchin.user_id = current_user.id
    #@punchin = Punchin.new(punch_params)
    @punchin = current_user.punchins.build(punch_params)
    @punchin.server_time = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    #@punchin.is_punched = true;

    #get current user from punchin
    @user = @punchin.user
    #set punched on user with true
    @user.punched_in = true;
    #update user
    @user.save
    #@punchin.user.punched_in = true;
    if @punchin.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Punched In!'
      # Tell the Punchinailer to send a notification email after save
      PunchinMailer.punchin_email(@punchin).deliver_later

      redirect_to punch_in_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Failed to edit Punch!'

      render :new
    end
  end

  # PUT method for updating in database a product based on id
  def update
    @punchin = Punchin.find(params[:id])
    if @punchin.update_attributes(punch_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Punchin updated!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Failed to edit Punchin!'
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE method for deleting a product from database based on id
  def destroy
    @punchin = Punchin.find(params[:id])
    if @punchin.delete
      flash[:notice] = 'Punchin deleted!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Failed to delete this Punchin!'
      render :destroy
    end
  end

  private
  # we used strong parameters for the validation of params
  def punch_params
    params.require(:punchin).permit(:server_time, :address_geoloc, :work_type, :work_desc, :user_id)
  end

  def show
    # method level rendering
    @punchin = Punchin.find(params[:id])
  end

  #when punched in
  def in
  end 

  def userout
    if user_signed_in?
      current_user.update_attributes(:punched_in => false)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
    end
  end
end
```

*And for info*: one punch belongs_to :user and users has_many :punches

I have a column in users table that says punched_in: true/false, and I only want that column to be set at false when I click on the link/button from view.

I have tried many solution, with link_to, button_to, different routes etc.
In this case, I get this error:

> The action 'userout' could not be found for PunchController

In other cases, my button worked but cannot reach the action that I want.

Thanks!

Comment: could you please post your route for `punch_controller` from terminal.

Comment: @Reboot userout POST   /punch/userout(.:format)       punch#userout

Comment: if you have changed your `routes.rb` file then try to  restart your server.

Comment: I restarted the server, but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have any namespace in your controller ?

Comment: Is it possible for us to see your controller code?

Comment: I have edited the initial post with the code from controller. It's a little messy because I took a lot of notes and I made a lot of changes, but I hope you cand handle it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action is private. Move it above the private line and it will work

Comment: Thank you very much! That was such a rookie mistake. I tought that private would end at the keyword 'end' from the method below. Thank you again!

Comment: No worries, always happy to help. Mark the answer as correct so that others can see they don't need to transfer this question now.

Comment: P.S. If you want to improve your style, install rubocop gem and run it against your app. It will call out all of the bad style choices and make your code 100x cleaner. I've only recently started using it and my style is already improving. I've been coding RoR for over 6 years

Comment: oh, didn't know about. will do! Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have some refactoring for you

```
def userout
  if user_signed_in?
    current_user.update_attributes(punched_in: false)
    redirect_to punch_out_path, notice: "You've been punched out" # what path do you want to redirect to?
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
  end
end
```

Can you run "rake routes" from the command line. Is the route in there?

Also what does the rails console say when you click the link.

Comment: Yes, I can see the route.
Thank you for refactoring, I'm learning so it's helping me a lot. The problem still persists.

Comment: Do you have class PunchController < ApplicationController at the top of the punch controller?

Comment: __Console content:__ AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'userout' could not be found for PunchController):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'

Comment: What does the console say too. That's probably going to be the next most helpful piece of info. Is there anything before the error. Like GET "path/blah" or POST etc

Comment: Ah maybe reboot is onto it. Have you restarted? Common mistake

Comment: My PunchController extends ApplicationController, so yes, I have that piece of code at the top of the controller. I don't know if this is helpful, but in routes I have also _resources :punch_

Comment: resources :punch will create the index, new, edit, create, update and destroy routes for the punch controller but should not affect any non standard routes

Comment: I have redeployed my app right now but the problem still exists.

Comment: I mention that my link_to button is alone, not in a form_for or something like that.

Comment: before the error, when I land on my page out.html.erb, where I have my link_to, my console says this also: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/defaults.js")

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem anything as it is not passing any form data.

Comment: Are you testing this locally?

Comment: Can you load the out page and wait for the console to finish printing everything. Scroll up in the console a couple of lines so that the automatic scrolling doesn't loose your place when you click the link. Go back to the browser and click the link. Paste the first few lines from the console after you clicked the link

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing this correctly, but here it is what i see in console: Started POST "/punch/userout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-24 19:24:36 +0300

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'userout' could not be found for PunchController):
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:132:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
 And yes I test this locally.